# Cannot convert from `GLib.TypeClass' to `GLib.ObjectClass'

Tags: vala, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to compile libfriends ([source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~super-friends/libfriends/trunk/files)) against valac (.28) and libgee (1.0). I specifically compiled these against Ubuntu-16.04 stack.

But I am getting following error

`` entry.vala:397.38-397.38: warning: if-statement without body
              if (_selected != value);
                                     ^
entry.vala:172.52-172.86: error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from `GLib.TypeClass' to `GLib.ObjectClass'
            binding_set = Gtk.BindingSet.by_class (typeof (InputTextView).class_ref ()); ``

I don't really find anything wrong with code. Any Idea?

The entire buildlog is here: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/263631082/buildlog_ubuntu-xenial-i386.libfriends_0.1.2+14.10.20140709+201606051415~ubuntu16.04.1_BUILDING.txt.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and it compiles with `valac-0.18`, but doesn't compile with `valac-0.28`.

So there must have been a change between those `valac` versions that does more strict type checking in this case.

`GLib.TypeClass` (really GTypeClass in C) [is the parent class](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#GObjectClass) of `GLib.ObjectClass` (really GObjectClass in C).

So the compiler is correct to not allow this without a cast. I don't know if the cast is correct in this situation, but it makes the code compile:

```
binding_set = Gtk.BindingSet.by_class ((ObjectClass) typeof (InputTextView).class_ref ())
```

See also valadoc for `GObjectClass` where a similar typecast is done in the example code:

http://valadoc.org/#!api=gobject-2.0/GLib.ObjectClass

Comment: It seems you are right. It does compile against vala-0.18. And your changed code works as well. Thanks.